# Python Selenium - Error: Element not Interactable. Interactive with website pop up window

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running a web scraper on my company's website so I can create elements every month. In testing, I have everything working until I get to interact with a pop up menu.

Code that interacts with pop up:

```
driver.get("www.website.com")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ButtonCreatePeriod").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "NoExpiration").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
ddelement2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='December 2021']")
action2 = ActionChains(driver)
action2.click(on_element=ddelement2).perform()
```

On `action2.click(on_element=ddelement2).perform()` I am getting the error:

**"Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLLIElement] has no size and location"**

I'm guessing this has to do with interacting with the popup.

Within the pop up that is opened with I click **"ButtonCreatePeriod"** I am opening the drop down menu defined as `class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown"`.Within this drop down, I need to select the option with the text "December 2021". I cannot use IDs or numerical values here since this varies across other UIs in the website. The options shown on the dropdown are scrollable which could be an issue too.

I used this same code on another UI on the website with no issues but that one did not present a pop up, although it was scrollable.

Any ideas as to how I could have it select "December 2021" here?

Error generated per @cruisepandey suggestion:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <span title="" class="k widget 
k-dropdown shorterDropDown k-state-disabled ic-dropdown-readonly" 
unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria- 
expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-
owns="MfrCoreTermEffectivePeriodKey_listbox" aria-live="polite" aria-
disabled="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-busy="false" aria-
activedescendant="l581310d-64f8-4bbc-9354-71b6f041d0e3" style="">...
</span> is not clickable at point (434, 383). Other element would 
receive the click: <p>...</p>

(Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)`
```

**Solution**

I basically had to dig deeper into the HTML code and use xpath to further define the lists within the drop down.

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='MfrCoreTermExpirationPeriodKey-list']//li[text()='December 2021']").click()
```

Comment: Can you share the full error stack trace ? Also, `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown").click()` try this

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks for the reply, sorry, new to this. What exactly do you mean by the "Full error Stack Trace"? I can provide a screenshot of what VSC is stating the bug is. Would that work?
I tried your code but I'm not sure I'm understanding. it looks like the `Class` element is gone from the `css_selector`?

Comment: When the script run, you must be seeing something getting printed in console right ? Generally if there's an error you'd see in red color in console .

Comment: @cruisepandey I gotcha. Here is the message straight from the terminal:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLLIElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)`

Comment: okay can you try this `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown").click()` code, prefer to put some sleep like `time.sleep(3)` before executing this code.

Comment: @cruisepandey I replaced `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown"]').click()` with yours and also added `time.sleep(3)` before that and it errored out again.

Comment: Same exception ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It's too long to post on comments. I added it to the bottom of the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons could be

1. Screen is not `maximized`, if so please maximize it when you launch the URL.

   ```
   driver.maximize_window()
   ```
2. `ActionChain` may help.

   ```
   time.sleep(5)
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown")).click().perform()
   ```
3. `JS intervention` with `scrollInto` view may help.

   ```
   time.sleep(5)
   ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown")
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
   ```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sending these over. Unfortunately, the script runs until the scroll drop down menu opens and then quits. The error continues to be "element not interactable"

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste `.k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown` and see if your desired element is getting highlighted. if it is getting highlighted then you must see on extreme right how many matches are present. something like 1/2 or 1/1 or 1/5, Please do that and let me know how many do you see ?

Comment: I am seeing 2 with `.k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown`. The other one states `k-state disabled` and `ic dropdown-readonly` because the system locks it. This is fine because I don't need to interact with it. But the one that is not readonly has no other identifiable information. I can paste both instances of the element section if that helps!

Comment: if this is getting highlighted `.k-widget.k-dropdown.shorterDropDown` with 1/2,  we should be okay, but pay attention not 2/2. It has to be 1/2.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to differentiate between the 2 on the `class` portion of the code other than the `k-state-disabled` and `ic-dropdown-readonly`.

1/2 (the read only one): `<span title class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown k-state-disabled ic-dropdown-readonly"`

2/2 (the one I want to use: `<span title class="k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown"`

Comment: Can you paste this into the console `(//span[contains(@class,'k-widget k-dropdown shorterDropDown')])[2]` ? you can change `[2]` to `[1]` or vice versa. Make sure the element we are looking for should have 1/1 matches

Comment: I found a solution by tinkering with the syntax of xpath. I pasted it at the end of the question I posted yesterday. It ended up having to do with the nesting structure of the HTML code and then find a specific item on the list of that structure.